# How to know whether a nifi process group has completed the data transfer using nipyapi?

Tags: python, api, apache-nifi

I have to know the status of data transfer job(flow inside a Process Group) whether it is completed, failed or is it running. I want to do this using nipyapi for a web application.

I have a process group in NiFi, inside which I have the NiFi flow. I am scheduling the process group using nipyapi:

```
nipyapi.canvas.schedule_process_group(id, True)
```

Now I want to monitor the status of the process group using nipyapi. By status I specifically want to know whether it's still running, failed or completed.

Comment: Can anyone also help me with ListSFTP or ListFile to check how many files are actually there in the folder. TIA :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a good solution for this problem. This is how i solved it. 
So i have a mysql db which basically keeps track of all the files that are to be transferred. The database table will have 2 columns. One for the Filename (lets say is unique) and flag for whether the file has been transferred (True and False).
[For Nifi Screenshot click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHm4H.png)

We have 3 section of processors.
`First: listSFTP and putMySQL
Second: getSFTP and putHDFS
Third: listHDFS and putHDFS`

First Section responsible for listing the files in SFTP. It Gets all the files and adds a row into the mysql that the Filename is 'X' and 'False' for not transferred yet.
`insert into NifiTest.Jobs values('${filename}', 0);`

Third Section does the same thing for HDFS. It will either insert with Transferred = True or update if already a row exists with the same file name. 
`insert into NifiTest.Jobs values('${filename}', 1) on duplicate key update TRANSFERRED = 1;` 
2nd Section does nothing but Send the file to the HDFS.

Now to check when the data transfer job is finished. 
You will start the entire process group together. When you query the Database and you get all Transferred = 1, that means the job is finished. 
It might feel like there are some cases where it might fail but when you carefully think out all the cases you will see that it takes care of all the situations. 
Let me know if i am wrong or some improvement can be made to this solution.

Answer (score 3):

NiFi does not really have a concept of a job that can be checked for completion. Once you start all the components in a process group, they are then running indefinitely until someone stops them.

The concept of being "done" or "complete" is really dependent on what you data flow is doing. For example, if your first processor is say GetFile, once that processor is running it is going to monitor the directory for files until someone stops the processor. While the processor is running it has no way of knowing if there will ever be more files, or if it has already seen all the files that will ever be dropped in the directory. That knowledge is only known by whoever/whatever is putting the files there.

To determine failure you need to do something in your data flow to capture the failures. Most processors have a failure relationship, so you would need to route these somewhere and take some action to track the failures.

Comment: how about using a ListSFTP or ListFile to know what files reside in the given folder? When the ListSFTP returns no files maybe then i can know that the transfer process is done. Can you tell me if that would be possible ?

Comment: How would ListSFTP/ListFile know that no more files are going to be written? What if its gets no files, then one second later a new file is written?

Comment: From the NiFi perspective the processor just stays running and keeps checking for new files, it doesn't stop until someone stops it from the UI (or Rest API)

Comment: When nifi gets a file from sftp and puts it in hdfs, it will delete the files from the sftp. So can i use listSFTP to see whether there are any files in that folder continually. When i see that there are no files in that folder i just stop the processor using the rest API and know that my data transfer job is complete

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without a database using Nifi process groups variable [registry APIs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) of process groups. Create a custom processor which sets a variable in process group lets say is_complete = true as last processor. Then you can monitor for this variable with nipyapi.